# CCD CDA to database using a scripting language

Tags: php, mysql, ccd, cda, c-cda

i need to write a script to extract medical info from a CCD Doc to a database (MySql). Afterwards, perform series of queries to generate report. I intend to use php as the scripting language. Any ideas from anyone will be appreciate.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Just wondering if anyone has an idea of how to go about this or a program out there that can help.

Answer (score 0):

There are no PHP 3rd party/open source libraries that I know of for this purpose as of today. At least not that I know of.

However if you see the OpenEMR implementation of the CCD parsing feature, I think you would get pretty much everything you want.

Look [here](https://gitorious.org/openemr/openemr/source/df6bcf68a87c5ae4f587394618f0958d99373e49%3alibrary/parse_patient_xml.php).

[OpenEMR](https://gitorious.org/openemr) is a free Open source, Practice management, Electronic Medical Records, prescription writing and medical billing application for Unix-like systems (Linux, UNIX, and BSD systems), Microsoft systems, Mac OS X and other platforms.